# How do I make javascript download files?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my download link to have a custom confirmation popup but I'm not sure how to do it. I've googled but everything that comes up doesn't help. Here is what I have:

JS:

```
<script>
        function confirm() {
            swal({
                title: "Wait,",
                text: "Click OK to confirm that you know what you are downloading.",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
               //download here.
            });
            } else {
                swal("Download cancelled.");
             }
            });
        }
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <div id="downloads">
            <a href="#" onclick="confirm()" class="download"><p>Dum Dum</p></a>
            <a href="FILE_downloads/iMessageSpammer.zip" download class="download"><p>iMessage Spammer</p></a>
            </div>
```

Does anyone know what I can do or any better methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but i use window.location="http://yourdomain.com/file=report.pdf";
It works for me.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

With HTML5 you simply add a `download` attribute to the anchor tag.

See [MDN <a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: While technically not the answer to the question, it's certainly is the better practice.

Comment: @ippi thanks. With the way browser security ebbs and flows, it seemed inappropriate to supply an answer that may eventually stop working.  If the OP had indicated that the server could be told to return a file, then perhaps a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways probably.

1. Use window.location function.
2. Make a get request or ajax call and
   return that file as response.